# How to track a location of any mobile device through j2me

Tags: java-me, mobile, location

I want to track the location (longitude and latitude) of the mobile through J2ME.
Please help me for this.and send me sample code how can i track the location of any mobile and send that information to the server.

Please help me for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J2ME (JSR 179) is a set of generic APIs that can be used for developing location-based services. See this links for your reference.

[Sample application...](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/f7e8ad78-7898-4053-ab83-74c147923866/MIDP_Location_API_Example_Tourist_Route_v1_0.zip.html)

[Location API article..](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/708ac992-1168-43b2-a46a-aa3931e49d48/MIDP_Location_API_Developers_Guide_v1_0_en.pdf.html)

[Sample Code...](http://mobilepit.com/05/javame-location-api-example-application-with-source-code.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the JSR-179 - Location API. If you google it you will find plenty of examples and tutorials, [here it's one of them, by Oracle-Sun](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/).